# ¿Cómo verifico que exista un determinado registro en una tabla con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql

Les cuento lo que estoy haciendo. He creado un botón en mi página web, que sirve para agregar productos a una "lista de deseos" a comprar en un futuro.

Lo que sucede es que, siguiendo el código que les dejo más abajo, cuando doy clic en el botón, se agrega dicho producto a la lista de deseos correctamente. PERO, si doy clic en el botón 10 veces, se agrega el mismo producto a la lista de deseos 10 veces.

Lo que yo necesito, es validar que si la tabla de mysql llamada "deseos" ya contiene un registro de dicho usuario y producto, no me agregue dicho producto a la lista de deseos nuevamente.

Código:

```
/*=============================================
AGREGAR A LISTA DE DESEOS
=============================================*/

static public function mdlAgregarDeseo($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id_usuario, id_producto) VALUES (:id_usuario, :id_producto)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":id_usuario", $datos["idUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT); 

    if($stmt -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt-> close();

    $stmt = null;

}

/*=============================================
MOSTRAR LISTA DE DESEOS
=============================================*/

static public function mdlMostrarDeseos($tabla, $item){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario ORDER BY id DESC");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":id_usuario", $item, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Comment: Antes del insert, hace un select a esa tabla con ese usuario y producto. si vuelve un registro, quiere decir que ya existe

Comment: Puedes crear una función que te haga la verificación. Por ejemplo: `function dataExists($tabla,$datos){ $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla WHERE ..."; //recuperas total y lo guardas en un ternario $bolStatus=($total>0) ? TRUE : FALSE;  return $bolStatus;}`  Luego, en `mdlAgregarDeseo` haces esto antes de insertar: `if (dataExists($tabla,$datos)) { //insertar }else{ //no insertar }`.  Así de simple.

Comment: Como te han contestado, creo que la solución es crear `primary key` con los dos campos

Comment: Muchas gracias todos por la respuesta, estaré probando a lo largo del día las ideas que me han dado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza una clave primaria compuesta por tus dos campos `id_usuario` e `id_producto`

```
ALTER TABLE deseos ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario, id_producto);
```

En caso de que ya tuvieses alguna `PRIMARY KEY` del estilo de `iddeseo` o algo así, puedes agregar una `UNIQUE KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE deseos ADD UNIQUE uk_deseos (id_usuario, id_producto);
```

Siendo `uk_deseos`el nombre que tú quieras.

De esta forma te aseguras que tu tabla estará bien **siempre** independientemente de si insertas desde PHP, si importas algún Excel o cualquier cosa.

Luego simplemente devolverías `error` como lo estás haciendo ya.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear una función de verificación, la cual invocarías antes de insertar.

Propongo esta función que además construirá una consulta con `WHERE` dinámico.

```
function dataExists($theTable,$theData)
{ 
    $theWhere = array();
    /*Agregamos cada nombre de columna y marcadores ?*/
    foreach($theData as $k=>$v)
    {
        array_push($theWhere, $k . "=?");
    }
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM $theTable";
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $theWhere);
    $theParams=array_values($theData);
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
    /*En PDO podemos pasar los parámetros en el execute como un array :)*/
    $stmt -> execute($theParams);
    $theTotal=$stmt->fetchColumn();
    $theStatus=($theTotal>0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    return $theStatus;
}
```

### ¿Cómo usarla?

Lo primero que **debes respetar de forma estricta es que en el array que la pasas, las claves deben ser exactamente los nombres de columnas que servirán de criterio en el `WHERE`**, pues la función ha sido pensada para que sea **dinámica**, de forma que funcione con cualquier tabla / columnas.

Por lo tanto, deberás pasarle un array parecido a esto:

```
$theData = array(
                     'id_usuario'=>1,
                     'id_producto'=>7
                );
```

Igualmente, como es lógico, el parámetro `$theTable` debe ser el nombre de la tabla sobre la que quieres consultar, por ejemplo:

```
$theTable="nombre_tabla";
```

La consulta preparada que creará la función en este caso será algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id_usuario=? AND id_producto=?
```

Nótese que en PDO podemos usar marcadores de `:nombre`, o marcadores de posición `?`. Aquí he optado por esta segunda posibilidad por conveniencia, practicidad y para darle flexibilidad al código, permitiendo un `WHERE` dinámico.

Entonces, `mdlAgregarDeseo` quedaría más o menos así:

```
static public function mdlAgregarDeseo($tabla, $datos){
    /*Vamos a recoger con esta variable para hacer un solo return*/
    $msgInfo="";
    /*Pasamos la información a nuestra función, la cual devolverá FALSE si no encuentra datos*/
    if (!dataExists($tabla,$datos)){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id_usuario, id_producto) VALUES (:id_usuario, :id_producto)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_usuario", $datos["idUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        if($stmt -> execute()){
            $msgInfo="ok";
        }else{
            $msgInfo="error";
        }   
        $stmt-> close();
    }else{
        $msgInfo="Datos repetidos, no se puede insertar";
    }
    return $msgInfo;
}
```

### Configuración a nivel de la base de datos

Puedes implementar `dataExists` aún configurando correctamente tus tablas mediante restricciones de unicidad como ha afirmado @Dibort en su respuesta.

Esto agregará un control adicional de datos duplicados, que nunca viene mal. Y, en el caso de usar el engine `InnoDB` evitará demasiados saltos en tus columnas auto-incrementales, las cuales aumentan aunque una consulta de inserción falle por ser un registro duplicado.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

> ### NB:
>
> Sería interesante seguir el criterio de `dataExists` para tus otros métodos. Si al array `$data` le dieras como nombres de clave los
>   nombres exactos de las columnas en la base de datos podrías construir
>   fácilmente consultas de inserción (o de otro tipo) de una manera
>   dinámica. De ese modo tendrías un CRUD que te puede servir para
>   cualquier tabla de tu sistema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan completa. Estaré a lo largo del día probando todo lo que me has dicho. Saludos compañero