# Como validar registro de php que no se repita?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buen día:
Estoy creando un archivo en php que se conecta a un localhost lo que requiero es hacer que valide en el localhost que no existan registros duplicados, la validación la tengo que hacer con el rfc(mexicano) ya que es un valor único.
Solicito de su apoyo ya que apenas estoy iniciando la carrera y no conozco php. Anexo el codigo que estoy usando

```
<?php require_once('coneccion.php');  

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellidopaterno = $_POST["apellidopaterno"];
    $apellidomaterno = $_POST["apellidomaterno"];
    $fechanacimiento= $_POST["fechanacimiento"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO persona (id, nombre, apellidopaterno, apellidomaterno, $fechanacimiento, rfc) ";

    $q.= "VALUES(0,'".$nombre."','".$apellidopaterno."','".$apellidomaterno."','".$fechanacimiento."','".$rfc."')";


    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
    if($r){
        $response["success"] = 1;
    } else{
        $response["success"] = 0;

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Esto se trató hace muy poco [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197414/29967).

Comment: gracias! no había encontrado la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero haber entendido la pregunta bien.

Podrías hacer esto para evitar duplicados:

```
    //Puedes poner la variable que quieras para verificar o varias
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE rfc = '".$rfc."'; 

    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    //Vemos si devuelve algo con el count(contar)
    if (count($r) > 0) {

          $sql_insert = "INSERT........";
    }
```