# Error al Validar un INSERT INTO de un foreach

Tags: php, php7

chicos tengo el siguiente codigo:

## Mi codigo

```
     <?php
 $lote = $_REQUEST['lote'];
        $lote_pedido = str_replace("    ", " ", $lote);
        $datos = $lote_pedido;
    // divides por espacios y cada 6 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
    $temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 6);
    $ar = array();


    foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
        // optienes el 1º elemento monto
        $ar[$key]['monto'] = array_shift($v);
        // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
        $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
        // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
        $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);

        $monto =   $ar[$key]['monto'];
        $codigo =  $ar[$key]['codigo'];
        $serial =  $ar[$key]['serial'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
            VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')"; 
           $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $error= (mysqli_error($db));


    }

    if (!$resultado_ingreso){
      $_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  = "Algo ha Ocurrido<br>" . $error;
    } else { // Aqui se ejecutan una serie de Update e Insert en otras tablas
```

### Lo que tengo y lo que hace

El Campo serial de la tabla tarjetas de mi base de datos posee clave UNIQUE Estoy tratando de que si alguno de los datos de los que estoy ingresando por alguna razon se repiten con alguno de los almacenados en la base de datos entonces no se efectue el INSERT de los datos que estoy ingresando.

Tal cual como esta si por alguna razon estoy ingresando los siguientes datos:

```
1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111111111111
2 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222222222222
```

Y en la base de datos ya existe el dato

```
1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111111111111
```

El sistema me indica el error de que existe el siguiente error:

> Duplicate entry '1111111111111' for key 'serial'

Pero efectua en INSERT del segundo dato y me gustaria de que no haga el INSERT pero que identifique cual de los datos es el que esta repetido.

Comment: Puedes implementar una función que verifique antes de insertar, llamarla pasándole los valores de la clave única y actuar en consecuencia. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197423/29967). Con respecto a tu código, ten en cuenta que es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL, para blindarlo debes implementar consultas preparadas. Lee sobre el tema, cuando puedas.

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano gracias por tu amable respuesta, en efecto he leido ese ejemplo que me refieres como 20 veces y he intentado como 12 veces y por mas que trato no lo logro implementar lo de manera correcta en mi codigo..!

Comment: De nada. Quizá la diferencia está en la implementación, puesto que allí se usa PDO y tú usas mysqli, además, allí se usan consultas preparadas (la forma de pasar los parámetros es distinta). Pero la lógica es la misma, es cuestión de adaptar el código, o pasar a usar PDO sustituyéndolo por mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Usa Transacciones. Antes del foreach, inicias la transacción, y le haces commit, al terminar el ciclo. Normalmente se usan junto con bloques try/catch (excepciones), de tal manera que en el CATCH puedes llamar rollback y salir del ciclo.

Documentación de [transacciones](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.begin-transaction.php)

Documentación de [excepciones](http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Gracias @Octavio_Galindo voy a leer sobre los temas que me refires a ver si logro implementarlo en mi codigo de manera correcta..!