# ¿Cómo se puede validar la duplicación de registros en una DB?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

> NOTA: Antes de que se indique que mi pregunta pueda ser una pregunta duplicada o algo más, informo que mi pregunta no apunta específicamente a evitar que hayan registros duplicados, sino a evitar que ciertos campos de una tabla se repitan.
>
> De la misma manera, como mi pregunta apunta a algo en especifico no se puede decir que es igual a otra pregunta, aunque en otra exista el mismo tema en cuestión, el cual es validar ciertas celdas.

Ya aclarado el punto primero que nada pido comprensión por que será un poco extensa esta pregunta, pero es necesario para que quede clara y concisa, gracias, ahora si procedo a explicar el tema:

Tengo un sitio que estoy desarrollando, el cual consiste en un registro de horarios para el uso de una cancha cualquiera, hasta el momento me funciona perfectamente. Solo me gustaría añadir una validación que permita evitar que ciertos campos en mi tabla se repitan, eso antes de enviar el formulario.

Adjunto la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos `horario_inicio` y `horario_fin` son los campos que me gustaría validar que no se repitan, ya que como mi sitio consisten en el registro de horarios, para arrendar canchas de uso multipropósito, no se pueden repetir las fechas, por ejemplo.

Si el horario 10AM-12PM esta ocupado por la cancha de Tenis, ***no se debería poder agregar nuevamente ese mismo horario para la misma cancha***. Eso es lo que me gustaría validar, pero **solo la fecha** en una primera instancia y **la hora** como validación adicional dentro de la misma.

Continuando con el ejemplo; pero luego la cancha de tenis está disponible para el resto del día el sitio debe permitir registrar otro horario. Esta vez evitando la validación de la fecha y obviamente ingresando un horario distinto.

> Lo que me gustaría validar es eso, que la fecha no se repita y el horario tampoco, pero como corresponde a un DATETIME la validación que tengo pensado realizar me tomará el valor por completo del campo, y no por horario.

Tenia pensado utilizar, antes de que haga su trabajo la siguiente linea de mi controlador en su función `store()`.

```
<?php
    public function store(){

        $horario->save(); //ESTA

    }
?>
```

Utilizar un **`IF-ELSE`** o  un **`foreach()`** o un **`for()`** para la validación, pero como mencione antes me tomaría el valor por completo del campo hora_inicio y del campo hora_final de la tabla de mi base de datos.

Es por eso que pensaba arreglarla estableciendo lo siguiente como por ejemplo:

**1er registro.**

El `cancha_id` para este registro es el 1.

`2018-08-05 08:00:00` Este registro está asociado a la cancha de tenis, con esa fecha como fecha y hora de inicio y `2018-08-05 09:00:00` como fecha y hora de término.

Además hay otro registro asociado a la misma cancha pero, la fecha es la siguiente:

**2do registro.**

`2018-08-05 10:00:00` Como fecha y hora de inicio y `2018-08-05 11:00:00` como fecha y hora de término.

La validación debería tomar en cuenta **la hora primero que todo (que no sean iguales)** entre ambos registros antes de pasar a **validar la fecha (como tendría horario diferente...)**; luego permitirá guardar, para este caso, el 2do registro.

Además para el caso de que haya un registro con los horarios:

10AM **[INICIO]** - 12PM **[TERMINO]** asociados a la cancha de tenis, y luego hay otro registro con los horarios 11AM-12PM para la misma cancha siendo el mismo dia, mes y año, a pesar de que las horas de inicio son diferentes no permita guardar un 2do registro ya que la cancha estará ocupada a las 10AM y se liberará a las 12PM.

Es decir en este caso la validación debería tomar que la fecha de termino no se repita.

RESUMO LAS VALIDACIONES que tengo pensado realizar:

**1°.** Validar que las fechas y horas no sean iguales para una misma cancha.

**2°.** Validar el horario que ocupará una cancha determinada.

**3°.** Validar que no se pueda ingresar un horario diferente, siendo que ya está ocupado por una cancha determinada.

De la misma manera como explique en los ejemplos.

Para todo esto se podrá ingresar cualquier otra fecha si:

**1°.** Corresponde a una cancha diferente, aunque sea el mismo dia, mes, y/o año.

**2°.** Corresponde a un día, mes y/o año diferente, aunque sea la misma cancha.

**3°.** Y por su puesto, si el horario es diferente o el mismo, siempre y cuando todo lo anterior se cumpla.

Cabe mencionar que cada ves que se registra un nuevo registro, éste ocupa un nuevo `id_horario`. Eso de momento no es importante para la validación ya que por defecto por ser clave primaria no se puede repetir.

Dejo mi código que llevo de momento:

Mis rutas en **web.php**

```
Route::resource('ListadoHorarios', 'HorariosCanchasController');
Route::get('ListadoHorarios', 'HorariosCanchasController@horarios');
Route::get('ListadoHorarios/{id?}', 'HorariosCanchasController@show')->name('ListadoHorarios.show');

Route::get('NuevoHorario/{id?}', 'HorariosCanchasController@mostrar')->name('ListadoHorarios.mostrar');
```

El formulario que incluyo en una vista que tengo.

```
<div>

<label>ID Horario</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
  </div>

<br>

<label>Fecha de Inicio</label>
<br>

<label>Seleccione una fecha y una hora</label>

  <div> 
    <input type="datetime-local" name="hora_inicio" id="hora_inicio">
  </div>

<label>Fecha de Término</label>
<br>
<label>Seleccione una fecha y una hora</label>
  <div>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="hora_fin" id="hora_fin">
  </div>


<label>Estado Horario ID</label>
<br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="estado_horario_id" id="estado_horario_id">
  </div>

<label>Cancha ID</label>
<br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="cancha_id" id="cancha_id" value="{{$canchas->id}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi controlador:

```
class HorariosCanchasController extends Controller
{
    public function horarios(){

      $horarios = HorariosNew::all();
      $complejos = ComplejosNew::all();

      return view('horarios.horarios_index', compact('horarios', 'complejos'));

    }

    public function show($id){

      $complejo = ComplejosNew::find($id);

      $cancha = CanchasComplejo::all();

      return view('horarios.MostrarComplejoHorario',  compact('complejo', 'cancha'));


    }


    public function mostrar($id){


      $canchas = CanchasComplejo::find($id);
      return view('horarios.NuevoHorario')->with('canchas', $canchas);

    }


    public function store(Request $request){


      $horarios = new HorariosNew();

      try {

        $horarios->id = $request->id;

        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i', $request->hora_inicio);
        $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\Th:i', $request->hora_fin);

        $horarios->hora_inicio = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $horarios->hora_fin = $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


          $horarios->estado_horario_id = $request->estado_horario_id;
          $horarios->cancha_id = $request->cancha_id;
          $horarios->save();


        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

           Session::flash('error', 'No se puede registrar el horario, pruebe proporcionando datos diferentes');

           return redirect()->route('ListadoHorarios.store');

        }

          Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
          return redirect()->route('ListadoHorarios.store');

    }
}
```

La función `store()` es donde tengo pensado agregar la validación dentro del `try()`.

Comment: *Lo que me gustaría validar es eso, que la fecha no se repita y el horario tampoco, pero como corresponde a un DATETIME la validación que tengo pensado realizar me tomará el valor por completo del campo, y no por horario.*  Al leer eso da la impresión de que estás pensando tratar una misma columna como si fueran dos, ¿por qué no validas el dato completo como un `DATETIME`?  ¿Por qué separas entre fecha y horario? Me parece que tu problema se presenta debido a un error de diseño en la base de datos, al no querer sacar el máximo provecho a tu columna del tipo `DATETIME`.

Comment: Eso es porque el campo esta guardado como un datetime y la base de datos lo muestra así: `2018-10-03 16:03:00`

Comment: porque no creas un indice unico , y en tu programa solo validarias si te da error

Comment: Por eso, a esa columna le agregas una restricción `UNIQUE` y la base de datos no te permitirá que se dupliquen valores. Luego, si quieres puedes controlar también por código para que la inserción no se haga. [Hace poco escribí una respuesta para validar desde PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197423/29967), pero aunque implementes eso, tu tabla debe tener una restricción `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Además si considero como un DateTime completamente, en la validación y una cancha está ocupada para las 10am y liberada a las 11am, despues no me permitirá agregar otro registro para la misma cancha ya que mi validación tomara el `cancha_id` como parámetro principal a validar.

Comment: No. Las restricciones `UNIQUE` pueden **combinar varias columnas**. Si en la tabla tu pones por ejemplo: `UNIQUE (cancha_id,fecha)` estarás indicando al manejador de BD que cree una restricción de unicidad basada en esas dos columnas, o lo que es lo mismo, que te permita repetir `cancha_id`, pero con fechas/horas diferentes.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Lo intente y no se puede me dice que esa columna está duplicada y ciertamente lo está, pero tu me dices... que te permite varios `cancha_id`... ¿entonces como sería?

Comment: Yo no me refiero a que crees otra columna en la tabla, sino a que le agregues una restricción, por ejemplo: `ALTER TABLE tu-tabla ADD UNIQUE unique_index (cancha_id,fecha);` donde `fecha`  sería  el nombre de la columna donde guardas la fecha y `tu-tabla` es el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Eso fue lo que explique, que no funcionó

Comment: Bueno comprendo que no funcione, la cuestión es ¿por qué?, ¿qué error dio?. Cuando se crean restricciones sobre tablas ya existentes, puede que los datos de la tabla no cumplan con esa restricción y haya que normalizarla. Pero sin saber qué error da nada se te puede sugerir.

Comment: @A.Cedano vuelvo a explicar, el error que me dio fue que el registro estaba duplicado, hay muchos registros, con diferentes horarios y una misma fecha, eso en un solo campo como datetime, hora_inicio, pero todos para la misma cancha, y por eso me arrojo el error por que esa cancha se repetía muchas veces.

Comment: A ver, la cuestión aquí es que no se repita el mismo `cancha_id`y `fecha`, **dando por supuesto que `fecha` es una columna del tipo `DATETIME` que va a almacenar los dos valores, la fecha y la hora**. ¿Estamos claros ahí? Yo te estoy proponiendo que **normalices los datos**. Al leerte, me parece que tú tienes por una parte la fecha, en una columna, y por otra parte la hora... así no va a funcionar, debes tener fecha y hora en una sola columna. De ese modo resuelves el problema de raíz, evitas redundancia de datos y el mantenimiento de la BD será mucho más fácil. No sé si me entiendes...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84014/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-m4urixd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, lo único que quieres validar es que las fechas y horas no se solapen con los registros que ya existen para evitar conflictos en el horario.

Si es así, hice estos pequeños ejemplos:

```
create table horario(id integer auto_increment primary key, cancha_id integer, hora_inicio datetime, hora_fin datetime);

insert into horario(cancha_id, hora_inicio, hora_fin) values 
(1, '2018-10-03 09:00', '2018-10-03 10:00'),
(1, '2018-10-03 10:00', '2018-10-03 11:00'),
(1, '2018-10-03 13:35', '2018-10-03 14:45'),
(1, '2018-10-03 16:00', '2018-10-03 17:00');
```

Ejemplos:

Quiero insertar un registro que empieza el '2018-10-03 09:00' y termina '2018-10-03 10:00' (registro duplicado).

```
select count(*) from horario
where 
    cancha_id = 1 and
    (('2018-10-03 09:00' >= hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 09:00' < hora_fin)
or  ('2018-10-03 10:00' > hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 10:00' <= hora_fin));
```

Quiero insertar un registro que empieza '2018-10-03 15:00' y termina '2018-10-03 16:00' (No debe haber problemas)

```
select count(*) from horario
where 
    cancha_id = 1 and
    (('2018-10-03 15:00' >= hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 15:00' < hora_fin)
or  ('2018-10-03 16:00' > hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 16:00' <= hora_fin));
```

Quiero insertar un registro que empieza '2018-10-03 14:30' y termina '2018-10-03 15:30' (La hora de inicio solapa con un registro existente, no debe insertarse)

```
select count(*) from horario
where 
    cancha_id = 1 and
    (('2018-10-03 14:30' >= hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 14:30' < hora_fin)
or  ('2018-10-03 15:30' > hora_inicio and '2018-10-03 15:30' <= hora_fin));
```

Con ese query puedes saber si existe algún registro que se solapa con las horas que quieres insertar.

Con ese query bien podrías crear un trigger before insert on horario, verificar si el resultado del query es > 0, si es > 0 puedes tirar una excepción, en otro caso puedes insertar libremente.

Trigger before insert on horario

```
DELIMITER //

create trigger horario_before_insert
before insert on horario for each row
begin 
    declare counting int;

    select count(*) into counting from horario
    where 
        cancha_id = NEW.cancha_id and
        ((NEW.hora_inicio >= hora_inicio and NEW.hora_inicio < hora_fin)
    or
        (NEW.hora_fin > hora_inicio and NEW.hora_fin <= hora_fin));

    if counting > 0 then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'EL nuevo registro no puede ser insertado, verifique la hora de inicio y fin.';
    end if;

end; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Insert de ejemplo:

```
insert into horario(cancha_id, hora_inicio, hora_fin) values (1, '2018-10-03 09:00', '2018-10-03 10:00');
```

Comment: bien sin embargo debería estar enfocado por lo que entiendo a funcionar dentro del ORM

Comment: Pues solo hay que traducirlo al ORM (no sé php, tampoco sé que ORM usa Laravel) al menos en RAILS con ActiveRecord sería fácil ejecutar el query que escribí.

Comment: @OrlandoMartinez. Lo que me refería al hablar del horario, era que si una cancha ya estaba ocupada en ese horario, no se podía agregar nuevamente la misma cancha y el mismo horario, ni la misma fecha claro. Como mencione antes, el registro iría a mi tabla _horarios_ el cual tiene un id, y un cancha_id, mi verificación debería tomar el cancha_id para luego verificar los otros campos, que seria la fecha y hora, antes de permitir ingresar un registro diferente o si es igual no lo deje aunque el id principal de la tabla horario sean distintos.

Comment: @M4uriXD Pues exactamente eso hace el trigger que escribí en la respuesta. Revisa el WHERE en el query, verifica el cancha_id, hora_inicio y hora_fin.