# Evitar registro duplicado mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Saludos tengo la siguiente funcion para agregar archivos a mi tabla paciente:

```html
 public function add(){
  $sql = "insert into ".self::$tablename." (name,lastname,address,phone,email,cedula,seguro,created_at)"  or die(mysql_error()) ;
  $sql .= "value (\"$this->name\",\"$this->lastname\",\"$this->address\",\"$this->phone\",\"$this->email\",\"$this->cedula\",\"$this->seguro\",$this->created_at)";
  Executor::doit($sql);
 }
```

y luego esto desde el boton agregar paciente:

```html
<?php

if(count($_POST)>0){
 $user = new PacientData();
 $user->name = $_POST["name"];
 $user->lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
 $user->address = $_POST["address"];
 $user->email = $_POST["email"];
 $user->cedula = $_POST["cedula"];
 $user->seguro = $_POST["seguro"];
 $user->phone = $_POST["phone"];

 $user->add();

print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=pacients';</script>";

}


?>
```

hay algunos campos con la condicion unico para que al usar or die(mysql_error()) salte un error si el registro esta duplicado pero no me funciona. Los registros no se insertan por datos duplicados pero el usuario no lo percibe ya que no da ninguna alerta. como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Podrías tener una función de comprobación a la que le pasarías: nombre de la tabla, columnas y valores. Esa función buscaría si el registro existe devolviendo `true` o `false`.  Aparte de eso, aclárate, ¿usas `mysql_` o `mysqli_`, en la etiqueta de la pregunta pusiste mysqli, pero tu código `mysql_error` es de la API `mysql_` la cual es obsoleta. Para esto que te digo lo mejor sería usar consultas preparadas (con `mysqli` o con PDO mucho mejor) y crearte una función de verificación. [Este es un ejemplo sencillo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197423/29967) usando PDO.

Comment: muchas gracias. otra duda, mi proyecto se maneja por vistas algo asi como esto: http://localhost/admin/index.php?view=home sin embargo si ponen directamente las vistas que quieran pueden acceder a ellas, como podria hacer que no puedan ir a la vista que desean si la escriben directamente arriba.

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla en PHP. Este código puede ser vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás poniendo el or die() a un string, deberías ponerlo en el Executor no?

```
    public function add(){
        $sql = "insert into ".self::$tablename." (name,lastname,address,phone,email,cedula,seguro,created_at)"  or die(mysql_error()) ;
        $sql .= "value (\"$this->name\",\"$this->lastname\",\"$this->address\",\"$this->phone\",\"$this->email\",\"$this->cedula\",\"$this->seguro\",$this->created_at)";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
```

Yo probaría con un try catch

```
public function add(){
     $sql = "insert into ".self::$tablename." (name,lastname,address,phone,email,cedula,seguro,created_at)";
     $sql .= "value (\"$this->name\",\"$this->lastname\",\"$this->address\",\"$this->phone\",\"$this->email\",\"$this->cedula\",\"$this->seguro\",$this->created_at)";
     try{
          Executor::doit($sql);
     }catch(exception $e){
          echo "ERROR: ".$e;
     }
}
```

Comment: intente el try catch pero igual no inserta pero tampoco presenta nada

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ¿y si lo haces a la vieja usanza?

```
$result = Executor::doit($sql); 
if($result == null || !$result){
   echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: tampoco. lo intente tanto con el echo como con el 
 print "<script>alert('Los datos introducidos estan duplicados');</script>";
pero igual no pasa nada

Comment: y si lo estamos enfocando mal y deberia de intentar el try catch en la segunda parte del codigo y no en la funcion misma?

Comment: por favor mira [answer], ¿qué es a la vieja usanza? por que crees que eso soluciona el problema, debes dar una explicación

Comment: Cuando digo "a la vieja usanza" me refiero a utilizar más código del necesario. Por ejemplo, no es necesario meter el resultado de la consulta en una variable y comprobar si existe o si devuelve nula, para eso hay funciones como el or die(), pero es otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final logre resolverlo de esta forma por si alguien mas necesita esto y ve mi pregunta:

```html
<?php

 $host_db = "localhost";
  $user_db = "root";
  $pass_db = "";
 $db_name = "bookmedikala";
  $tbl_name = "pacient ";
  $user = new PacientData();
  $user->name = $_POST["name"];
  $user->lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
  $user->address = $_POST["address"];
  $user->email = $_POST["email"];
  $user->cedula = $_POST["cedula"];
  $user->seguro = $_POST["seguro"];
  $user->phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $user->username = $_POST["username"];
 $user->password = $_POST["password"];

  $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

  if ($conexion->connect_error) {

  die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
 }

  $buscarCedula = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE cedula = '$_POST[cedula]' ";

  $result = $conexion->query($buscarCedula);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count == 1)
  {
   print "<script>alert('Existe otra persona con esta cedula, favor validar e intentar nueva vez.');</script>";
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=registro';</script>";
  }

 else
 {
  $buscarUser = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' ";

  $result = $conexion->query($buscarUser);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count == 1)
  {
   print "<script>alert('Existe otra persona con este usuario, favor colocar un usuario diferente.');</script>";
   print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=registro';</script>";
  }
  else
  {
   $buscarEmail = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' ";

  $result = $conexion->query($buscarEmail);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count == 1)
  {
   print "<script>alert('Existe otra persona con este correo electronico, favor colocar un correo diferente.');</script>";
   print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=registro';</script>";
  }

  else

  {
   $user->add();
   print "<script>alert('Usuario registrado de forma satisfactoria');</script>";
   print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=login';</script>";

  }

 }
}


mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```