# Diferencias entre consultas con marcadores

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Cual es la diferencia en SEGURIDAD Y RENDIMIENTO entre ejecutar una consulta de esta manera:

```
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = " INSERT INTO cliente(c_cedula, c_nombre, c_correo, c_telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($_POST['cedulacliente'], strtoupper($_POST['nombrecliente']), $_POST['correocliente'], $_POST['telefonocliente']));
    Database::disconnect();
```

Con respecto a esta manera:

```
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = " UPDATE investigacion_super SET invsup_caso_ingestigacion = :investigacion WHERE invsup_numero_apertura = :apertura ";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindParam(":investigacion", $investigacion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(":apertura", $apertura, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q->execute();
    Database::disconnect();
```

Quisiera saber cual es la mejor manera de usarla, en caso de que pueda haber una manera más eficiente y segura que las dos, por favor me la podrian compartir, que me pueda ser útil para un SELECT.

Comment: Diego las dos son iguales y son seguras. En cuanto a la eficiencia, no hay nada probado de que una sea más eficiente que la otra. Y, hay más formas, por ejemplo con los marcadores de nombre también se puede pasar un array en el `execute` haciendo algo así:  `$arrParams=array(":marcador1"=>$valor1, ":marcador2"=>$valor2); $stmt->execute($arrParams);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cuanto a la **seguridad** no hay ninguna diferencia. Ambas formas de escribir las sentencias preparadas son seguras.

En cuanto al **rendimiento** no hay nada que pruebe que una forma tenga más rendimiento que la otra y en caso de que haya diferencias me parece que serían ínfimas.

Los marcadores de posición `?` tienen la dificultad de que hay que ser cuidadosos cuando asignas los datos. Si te equivocas en el orden de los datos en el array podrías cometer una catástrofe en la base de datos, poniendo valores intercambiados en las columnas.

Por ejemplo:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$mData=array($apellido,$nombre);  #Cuando no estás pendiente de las cosas
$stmt->execute($mData);
```

Ahí estarías ingresando el apellido en lugar del nombre y viceversa.

Eso podría ocurrir con los marcadores de `:nombre` también, pero habría que ser muy despistado, para hacer esto:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido) VALUES (:nombre,:apellido)";
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":nombre",   $apellido, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":apellido", $nombre,   PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Al menos de darás cuenta (digo yo) que las cosas están al revés.

---

Hay que decir que para contextos en que se requiere una consulta dinámica, combinar marcadores de posición `?` con la posibilidad de pasar los datos como array en el `execute` tiene sus ventajas, porque hace muy simple construir por ejemplo un `WHERE` dinámico ([ver aquí por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197423/29967)), o crear consultas mucho más complejas con criterios opcionales y cosas parecidas.

---

Finalmente, para completar el abanico, PDO permite pasar también un array que usa marcadores de `:nombre` directamente en el `execute`.

Esto, por tanto, también es posible sin ningún riesgo.

```
$arrParams=array(":marcador1"=>$valor1, ":marcador2"=>$valor2); 
$stmt->execute($arrParams);
```