# ¿Cómo crear bindParam() dinámicos con Javascript y PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, array, pdo

Tengo una necesidad para realizar búsquedas en `MySQL` con `php` utilizando `PDO` por lo que me surgio una duda.

Tengo una función `php` con un `switch` ya que haré búsquedas en diferentes tablas y dependiendo de esto sera el contenido del `query`

```
public function statmentSQL($tabla, $datos){
 
   switch ($tabla) {
        case 'ejemplo':
         $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabla." " ...; 
         break;  
        ...
        
    }
}
```

Lo que he hecho por mucho tiempo es concatenar los valores, pero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que yo al mandar un `JSON` o `Array` mediante `$.ajax()` pueda iterarlo en la función `PHP` y a mi query agregarle los signos de interrogación `(?)

Es aquí donde surge mi duda de que si es posible agregar los `PDOStatement::bindParam` dinámicos para asignarle valor a los signos de pregunta, es decir:

Mando mediante un array los valores que se utilizarán en los filtros, del lado del `php` iterarlos y asignarles los signos de interrogación, para el backend es desconocido la cantidad de datos que se envían para hacer la consulta, por lo tanto el número y tipo de `bindParam()`  está sujeto a la cantidad de datos enviados para hacer los filtros, por lo que mi duda es ¿Si se pueden crear `bindParam()`  dinámicos?

Para concretar más la pregunta pondré un ejemplo:

En la variable `$datos` envío tres datos para hacer el filtro (entero, texto, entero)

Por lo que al desconocer la cantidad de datos enviados no tengo `bindParam()`  definidos por lo que requiero crearlos conforme a la información enviada, es decir crear tres `bindParam()`  para entero, texto y entero de manera dinámica.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mas tu duda por favor? pues no la termino de entender

Comment: Si puedes. Adicionalmente, puedes hacer algo como: `'... WHERE campo1 = :valor1 AND campo2 LIKE :valor2 ...'` y luego usar $smtp->prepare($query) para crear una sentecia preparada y ejecutar haciendo `$valores = [':valor1' => elvalor, ':valor2' => otrovalor, ...];` y luego PDO se encarga del bind  cuando uses `$smtp->execute($valores);` dónde $smtp es tu sentencia preparada y puedes iterar sobre ella pasando diferentes arrays de valores

Comment: Consulta [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: @BetaM agrega más información a la pregunta, espero y pueda darme a entender

Comment: los 3 valores son necesarios en conjunto?, es decir si llegan 3 las 3 condiciones se deben cumplir o con que uno de resultados entonces se procesa la consulta?

Comment: Las tres tendrían que cumplirse para hacer más exacto  la búsqueda en la consulta

Comment: `"Where ID =". "(?)". " nombre Like (?) %". "status =". "(?)" ` por ejemplo los datos se agregaron dependiendo de los datos enviados yos concatené en base a eso (perdón si tengo errores en el texto) dinamicamente debería crear los `bindParam() ` para agregarles su valor y tipo

Comment: El método **`dataExists()`** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/197423/29967) hace precisamente lo que quieres.  En `$theTable` mandarías el nombre de la tabla y en `$theData` mandas un array asociativo con el/los nombre/s de columna/s y valor/es.

Comment: Estoy viendo y es interesante tendré que probar, pero creo que haré una mezcla con ambas respuestas

Comment: Si Ferny por eso cuando vi el link tenía que recomendarte darle una mirada, incluso si posterior a eso construyes una respuesta alterna entonces te invito a publicarla

Comment: En cuanto tenga tiempo lo probaré y ya marco o agrego una respuesta a la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Considero que:

- No necesitas *pensar `bindParams()` dinámicos*
- Lo que si debes construir con atención a la sintaxis es el uso del operador `LIKE`

  - Misma que declararemos fuera de la sintaxis SQL principal y lo que haremos será concatenarlo como valor adjunto de la variable indicada
- Puedes con la data que te llega del frontend construir un array asociativo en el backend donde:

  - Las claves serán los valores que recuperemos en los `bindParam`
  - Los valores asignados serán las variables que previamente igualamos con los valores que llegaron del frontend
- Desde un inicio podemos dejar la cantidad fija de `bindParam` en la consulta, aquellos que no reciban valores entonces se convierten en `NULL`
- A la lógica que considero le debes prestar mas atención es al flujo de la consulta

Propuesta de consulta:

Aquí igualamos N cantidad de variables con los datos que te llegan del frontend (*claramente yo puse valores hardcodeados*)

```
$valorUnoConsulta = 1;
$valorDosConsulta = 'be';
$valorTresConsulta = 7687696976;
$valorLike = '%'.$valorDosConsulta;
```

Construyo el *array asociativo*

```
$datosConsulta = [
                    "valorUnoConsulta" => $valorUnoConsulta,
                    "valorDosConsulta" => $valorLike,
                    "valorTresConsulta" => $valorTresConsulta,
                ];
```

A nivel de la consulta indico en los `bindParams` las claves del array asociativo del cual extraremos los valores que ocupamos en la consulta

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = :id AND name LIKE :name AND algun_valor = :algun_valor");
$consulta->bindParam(":id", $datosConsulta["valorUnoConsulta"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->bindParam(":name", $datosConsulta["valorDosConsulta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->bindParam(":algun_valor", $datosConsulta["valorTresConsulta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute();
```

Si necesitas ir haciendo *debug* de tu consulta, entonces apóyate del método [debugDumpParams()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) la cual te arrojará la impresión de data importante respecto al `SELECT` que tratas de construir mediante PDO

```
$consulta->debugDumpParams();
```

El método anterior lo podemos comentar cuando deje de resultarnos útil y entonces ya trabajar con la consulta de forma regular.

Al final, dependiendo de las reglas que estableciste a cumplir dentro del `SELECT` y los valores que le hagas o no llegar a la query entonces serán los resultados que puedes o no obtener.

Comment: Excelente es una buena alternativa, me ayudará mucho la respuesta

Comment: Inclusive no se si funcione, puede estar declarado los bind para mas comunes los cuales mediante loops y comparaciones puedo ir llenando con el array asiciativo.

Comment: Lo último que mencionas aún no lo compruebo pero puede ser opción, te invito a no marcar está como aceptada, te recomiendo esperar otros aporte este fue solo uno pero seguro llega uno mejor

Comment: Por ejemplo veo que A Cedano propone en los comentarios algo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Para elaborar la solución a que yo llegué me base en la aportación de los comentarios de la pregunta; Dejo [Aquí el aporte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197414/c%C3%B3mo-verifico-que-exista-un-determinado-registro-en-una-tabla-con-php/197423#197423), también utilicé las respuestas aportadas anteriormente en la pregunta..

**Mi propuesta al probelma**

Arreglo con los datos

```
$data = [
   array("Tabla"=>"Rol","Columna" => "id", "Patron_Busqueda" => "=", "Dato_Busqueda" => "?", "Dato" => 1 ),
   array("Tabla"=>"Rol","Columna" => "nombre", "Patron_Busqueda" => "LIKE", "Dato_Busqueda" => "CONCAT(?,'%')", "Dato" => "A"),
   array("Tabla"=>"Rol","Columna" => "Estatus", "Patron_Busqueda" => "=", "Dato_Busqueda" => "?", "Dato" => 1),
];
```

(No se si es una buena práctica) pero en el arreglo envío todos los campos posibles a utilizar con sus respectivos valores.

La función que utilizare recibe dos parámetros `$table` y `theData`, en el primero recibo el nombre de la tabla en la que se hará la consulta y en el segundo la información del arreglo.

Establecí las variables a utilizar dentro de mi función `PHP`

```
    $conexion = ConnectionBD::getCurrentInstance();  
    $bindParams_Array = array() ;
    $sql = '';
```

**`$bindParams_Array`: ** Se almacenan en el array los valores de los parámetros a enviar dentro del `PDO::execute` el cual acepta `arrays` con los valores de las incógnitas [Documentación del PDO::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php).

Como mi función será reutilizada en diversas consultas con tablas diferentes, opté por utilizar un `switch` para crear la consulta `SQL` dependiendo de la tabla (cada tabla arroja columnas diferentes por eso se debe de crear conforme a la necesidad de la consulta).

```
  switch ($table) {
       case 'rol':                
           $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table. ' ';
           break;
   }
```

Después de haber establecido la estructura básica de la consulta, procedemos a agregar las condiciones (Filtros) para realizar búsquedas especificas en nuestra tabla, por lo que se utiliza un `foreach` para recorrer el arreglo y de esta forma agregar los datos a la cadena de texto `$sql` y agregarlos mediante concatenación `.=`; Así también agregar los valores de las incógnitas dentro del array `$bindParams_Array`

```
foreach ($theData as $index => $filtros) {           
       if ($index == 0) {
           $sql .= " WHERE ";
       }else{
            $sql .= " AND ";
       }
       $sql .= $filtros["Tabla"].".".$filtros["Columna"]." ".$filtros["Patron_Busqueda"]." ".$filtros["Dato_Busqueda"];
       array_push($bindParams_Array, $filtros["Dato"]);
    }
```

y por ultimo ejecutamos nuestra consulta y obtenemos el resultado de ella

```
try {
        $conexion->Connect();
        $conexion->pdo->beginTransaction();
        $statement = $conexion->pdo->prepare($sql);
        if($statement->execute($bindParams_Array)){
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            var_dump($resultado);
            $conexion->pdo->commit();   
            //echo true;             
        }else{
            $conexion->pdo->rollBack();
            echo false;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
        $conexion->pdo->rollBack();
    }
```

El arreglo fue de prueba, pero esos mismos datos pueden enviarse mediante `$.ajax()` como `JSON` y utilizar [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para convertirlos en objetos `PHP`